# HTTP get request won't submit with a URL encoded parameter

Tags: asp.net, http, url, get

I'm currently writing an ASP.NET Core web API that has an action with a encrypted value as a parameter.

I'm trying to test this action and the URL won't even submit in the web browser, at first I thought it could be due to the URL being too long but I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) and my URL is well below the 2000 character limit. I've changed the parameter to a trivial string ("hello") and it submits fine and runs the code. I've tried in both Edge and IE11 whilst debugging my application, in Edge nothing happens at all, in IE11 I get a message saying:

> Windows cannot find 'http://localhost:5000/api/...' Check the spelling and try again

In either case the code in the application doesn't execute (I've put a breakpoint on the first line of the controllers constructor which isn't being hit).

I've included an example of one of the URLs that isn't working below, as well as the code I'm using to generate the encrypted string, it uses [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3221zfcx(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the encrypted `byte[]` array to a string.

Example URL (one that doesn't work):

> http://localhost:5000/api/testcontroller/doaction/%95%d6%f8%97%84K%1f%d4%40P%f0%8d%de%27%19%ed%ffAR%9c%c6%d4%b1%83%1e%9fX%ce%9b%ca%0e%d4j%d3Rlz%89%19%96%5dL%b1%16%e9V%14u%c7W%ee%89p%3f%f7%e6d%60%13%e5%ca%00%e9%a2%27%cb%d3J%94%a6%e1%b9%9c%914%06y%7e%0bn%ce%00%e5%7d%98b%85c%fa6m%7d%f7%f1%7b8%26%22%5e%1et%5e%10%0c%05%dd%deFAR%bb%93L%b9-W%e1K%82%d8%cc8%ce%e0%0c%2b%bc%19

Action:

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{encrypted}")]
public string DoAction(string encrypted)
{
    return "Executed";
}
```

Generate encrypted string:

```
private string GenerateEncryptedString()
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    byte[] data = HttpUtility.UrlDecodeToBytes("AHMW9GMXQZXYL04EYBIW");
    byte[] encryptedData = rsaProvider.Encrypt(data, true);
    string encryptedString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encryptedData);
    return encryptedString;
}
```

Not sure if I'm going wrong in my methodology for converting the encrypted data to a string but I would appreciate any feedback on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to pass this data in the query string and not in the location (*path*) part of the url (some characters may be forbidden in paths as a security layer), so add a `?data=` before the encoded data.

http://localhost:5000/api/testcontroller/doaction/?data=%95%d6%f8%97%84K%1f%d4%40P%f0%8d%de%27%19%ed%ffAR%9c%c6%d4%b1%83%1e%9fX%ce%9b%ca%0e%d4j%d3Rlz%89%19%96%5dL%b1%16%e9V%14u%c7W%ee%89p%3f%f7%e6d%60%13%e5%ca%00%e9%a2%27%cb%d3J%94%a6%e1%b9%9c%914%06y%7e%0bn%ce%00%e5%7d%98b%85c%fa6m%7d%f7%f1%7b8%26%22%5e%1et%5e%10%0c%05%dd%deFAR%bb%93L%b9-W%e1K%82%d8%cc8%ce%e0%0c%2b%bc%19